# Implementing an Unpublished API

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have an iOS library on which I would like to expose certain methods to **my** apps which consume that API but explicitly disallow calling those methods from other apps.

Right now I have my internal methods in an special header `Foo+Internal.h` which has an `(internal)` category extension on my classes. Only my app includes this file but how could I actively disallow someone else from using these methods?

Comment: But libraries in iOS are static and not dynamic, which means they have to be statically linked to, so the only way another app could use your library is if you physically give them a copy of it to include in their Xcode project. Are you saying you are distributing your library yet still want to limit accessibility to it??

Answer (score 1):

If you were simply talking about C functions, then you could put all of your source into one translation unit and declare the internal functions `static`.

But since you're talking about methods on Objective-C classes, the answer is that, ultimately, you can't. If the methods are in your library, and you give the library to others, then they can call the methods.

If the internal methods are independent of the rest of the library, you can create an external version of the library (for your customers) and an internal version (for your own use). Don't include the internal methods in the external library.

You could also try to obfuscate the names of the internal methods using #defines.

Comment: It's important to note that even in the C case, the caller can still get to the functions with a little reverse engineering. They're in memory in your applications program space; they're callable. They just won't be quite so trivially exposed and documented in the way they are in ObjC or exported C.